# Error running Python Script, Web Scraping code

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new to Py and am building a web scraper. Unfortunately, I am running into an error when I try running the script. When I run it with Python 3.8, it says:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

[image: Py error]

My task is to create a web scraper that collects the HTML from a website. Then identify all URLs. The final project should be a CSV file that has all duplicate URLs removed and only unique ones kept.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[9]:


import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# In[25]:


# retrieving/Scraping data including duplicates
url = 'https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html'
results = requests.get(url)
raw = results.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw,'html.parser')

#collecting tags href
tags = soup.find_all('a', href = True)


# In[26]:


# HTML .txt 
with open('html_raw.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as html_raw:
    html_raw.write(str(soup))


# In[17]:


# raw HTML
print(soup.prettify())


# In[27]:


# creating set that removes dups
clean_set = set()

# loop
for tag in tags:
    href= tag.get('href')
    if href.startswith('None'):
        continue
    elif href.startswith('#'):
        continue
    elif href.startswith('/'):
        clean_set.add('https://www.census.gov' + href)
    elif href.startswith('#http'):
        clean_set.add(href[1:])
    else:
        clean_set.add(href)


# In[13]:


# number of URLs duplicates removed
print ('Count of URLs duplicates removed: ', len(clean_set))


# In[28]:


# CSV final count
f_list= (list(clean_set))


# In[29]:


# CSV
with open('C996_Py_Census.csv', 'w') as links_CSV:
    thewriter = csv.writer(links_CSV)
    for url in f_list:
        thewriter.writerow([url])
        
links_CSV.close()


# In[ ]:
```

Comment: Did you install `requests`?

Comment: 3rd-party modules must be installed before use. Have you installed `requests`?

Comment: I believe I have installed it correctly. When I go to do PIP install it says requirements already satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this can happen when you have multiple versions of Python installed. Your pip command could be installing the requests module under a different version of Python than what your script uses. I would try to running this: "py -3 -m pip install requests." If that doesn't work delete and re download python. Make sure it's added to .Path during the install process.